# How can I replace flat text file with mysql database lookup

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am currently using a flat txt file to retrive data and put it into an array.  Here's the php for retriving the data and insert into array:

```
$f  = fopen( 'redirects.txt', 'r' );
$urls   = array();

// The file didn't open correctly.
if ( !$f ) {
    echo 'Make sure you create your redirects.txt file and that it\'s readable by the redirect script.';
    die;
}

// Read the input file and parse it into an array
while( $data = fgetcsv( $f ) ) {
    if ( !isset( $data[0] ) || !isset( $data[1] ) )
        continue;

    $key = trim( $data[0] );
    $val = trim( $data[1] );
    $urls[ $key ] = $val;
}
```

How can I replace this approach for retrieving the data from a mysql database tabel.

The table is my_table
The key would be the column named 'title'
and the value would be the column named 'url'

Then the array data is then used as follows:

```
$url = ( isset( $urls[ $id ] ) ) ? $urls[ $id ] : ( isset( $urls[ 'default' ] ) ? $urls[ 'default' ] : false );
```

Comment: Does the example under [PDOStatement:fetchAll](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) help?

Comment: 1) Write SQL 2) Use mysqli or PDO in PHP to execute that sql 3) fetch results from query 4) build array from results